# Sending and Receiving back JSON data in Android Studio

Tags: android, json

I've successfully retrieved data from my website, but I can't send information and check what I've sent.
I have read a lot of threads here, none of them were able to help me. Here's my JSON data sender function.

```
protected void sendJson(final String email, final String pwd) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://www.google.com.br/mobile/test/");

                json.put("name", email);
                json.put("senha", pwd);

                Log.d("TAG InfoDesejada", json.toString());
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                Log.d("TAG StringEnviada", se.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);


                /*Checking response */
                if (response != null) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                    Log.d("TAG TextoEnviado4", response.toString());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
            }

            Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

Then I call in the mainActivity: `sendJson("email@dot.com", "password");`

I'm not sure if I am sending the data correctly, but if I am I don't know how to retrieve it, or work with this data anyway.
Really need help. Thanks.

Comment: this sendJson function is called onCreate()?

Comment: Yes. Its called onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put methods in OnCreate() that take some time to execute on the UI Thread. 
I would like to recommend using AsyncTask.

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. 
This class allows you to perform **background** **operations** and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

This example:

```
  private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
             int count = urls.length;
             long totalSize = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                 totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
                 publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
                 // Escape early if cancel() is called
                 if (isCancelled()) break;
             }
             return totalSize;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
             showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");


  }
 }
```

Once created, a task is executed very simply:

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```